# Laravel REST API: how to map database column name with another name for parameters?

Tags: laravel, api

I have a column named `location_relationship_id` which is a relationship that belongs to `Location` model.

In postman, this parameter works: `http://localhost/api/v1/traffic-violations?location_relationship_id=25`

Results:

```
 "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "violationType": "Pass traffic light",
            "location": "Al-Morooj",
            "workingShift": "(B) Evening",
        }
    ],
```

In the json, the naming/mapping is correct. As you can see it's named `location` rather than `location_relationship_id`.

How can I replace the url to be something like this: `http://localhost/api/v1/traffic-violations?location=Al-Morooj`? Or should I leave it as is and not bother?

When I do this I get a column doesn't exist error (obviously).

I am using this package to return the data [itsrennyman/laravel-rest-filters](https://github.com/itsrennyman/laravel-rest-filters#advanced-filters)

**This is my controller:**

```
/**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $violations = TrafficViolation::withRestFilters();
        return new TrafficViolationCollection($violations->paginate());
    }

    /**
     * Display a specified resource
     * @param \App\Models\TrafficViolation $violation
     * @return Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        return new TrafficViolationResource(TrafficViolation::findOrFail($id));
    }
```

**And this is my Resource class:**

```
class TrafficViolationResource extends JsonResource
{
    // Define the mapping configuration for each field
    private const MAPPING = [
        'location_relationship_id' => ['key' => 'location', 'method' => 'mapLocationField'],
        'violation_type_relationship_id' => ['key' => 'violationType', 'method' => 'mapViolationTypeField'],
        'working_shift_relationship_id' => ['key' => 'workingShift', 'method' => 'mapWorkingShiftField']
    ];

    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return $this->transformData(parent::toArray($request));
    }

    /**
     * Transform the data by excluding specified fields and mapping the remaining fields.
     *
     */
    private function transformData(array $data): array
    {
        return collect($data)
            ->except('created_at', 'updated_at')
            ->mapWithKeys(function ($value, $key) {
                // Check if the field has a mapping configuration
                if (array_key_exists($key, self::MAPPING)) {
                    $mapping = self::MAPPING[$key];
                    // Invoke the corresponding mapping method and pass the value and output key
                    return $this->{$mapping['method']}($value, $mapping['key']);
                }
                // If no mapping exists, convert the field to camel case
                return [Str::camel($key) => $value];
            })
            ->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * Map the 'location_relationship_id' field by accessing the relationship and transforming the value.
     */
    private function mapLocationField($value, $key): array
    {
        $name = $this->locationRelationship->name;
        return [$key => $name];
    }

    /**
     * Map the 'violation_type_relationship_id' field by accessing the relationship and transforming the value.
     */
    private function mapViolationTypeField($value, $key): array
    {
        $name = $this->violationTypeRelationship->name;
        return [$key => $name];
    }

    /**
     * Map the 'working_shift_relationship_id' field by accessing the relationship and transforming the value.
     */
    private function mapWorkingShiftField($value, $key): array
    {
        $name = $this->workingShiftRelationship->name;
        return [$key => $name];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, the plugin you are using does not support this out of the box. But good news is that the plugin itself is very simple ( just two classes ), so lets ditch it for now and try implementing it ourself in your application

So there are two classes, `Attribute` and `RestServiceProvider`

[RestServiceProvider.php](https://github.com/itsrennyman/laravel-rest-filters/blob/master/src/RestServiceProvider.php) will mostly also be identical. Let's change its namespace and add option to map fields, like

```php
// This is where we will map field names
if (property_exists($model, 'fieldMapping')) {
    $field = $model->fieldMapping[$field] ?? $field;
}
```

So
`app/Providers/RestServiceProvider.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\RestFilters\Helpers\Attribute;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class RestServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register bindings in the container.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Builder::macro('withRestFilters', function () {
            // Model Instance
            $model = $this->getModel();
            // Filtering
            $query = request()->query->all();

            // Needs to exclude key items like "sort"
            collect($query)->except(['sort', 'fields', 'embed', 'page'])
                ->except($model->bannedFields ?: [])
                ->each(function ($value, $field) use ($model) {

                    // This is where we will map field names
                    if (property_exists($model, 'fieldMapping')) {
                        $field = $model->fieldMapping[$field] ?? $field;
                    }

                    // Check has Multiple Filters
                    if (Str::contains($value, ',')) {
                        $this->whereIn($field, Str::of($value)->explode(','));
                    } else {
                        // Empty value. Skip.
                        if (empty($value)) {
                            return true;
                        }

                        // Check has an extra attribute
                        if (Str::contains($value, ':')) {
                            $attributeAndValue = Str::of($value)->explode(':');

                            // Check Banned Attributes
                            if ($model->bannedAttributes && in_array($attributeAndValue[0], $model->bannedAttributes)) {
                                return true;
                            }

                            // Replace Attribute
                            $replacedAttribute = Attribute::sobstitute($attributeAndValue[0]);

                            // If not exists returns false, so not considered.
                            if (!$replacedAttribute) {
                                return true;
                            }

                            $this->where($field, $replacedAttribute, $attributeAndValue[1]);
                        } else {
                            $this->where($field, '=', $value);
                        }
                    }
                });

            // Selecting Fields
            if (request()->filled('fields')) {
                $fields = Str::of(request()->fields)->explode(',');

                $fields->each(function ($field) {
                    $this->addSelect($field);
                });
            }

            // Sorting
            if (request()->filled('sort')) {
                $fields = Str::of(request()->sort)->explode(',');

                $fields->each(function ($field) {
                    $sortDirection = Str::startsWith($field, '-') ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';

                    $this->orderBy(Str::replaceFirst('-', '', $field), $sortDirection);
                });
            }

            // Embedding (Needs to add id field if filtered.)
            if (request()->filled('embed')) {
                $fields = Str::of(request()->embed)->explode(',');

                $fields->each(function ($field) {
                    $this->with($field);
                });
            }

            return $this;
        });
    }
}
```

[Attribute.php](https://github.com/itsrennyman/laravel-rest-filters/blob/master/src/Helpers/Attribute.php). This can be left unchanged, lets just change the namespace
`/app/RestFilters/Helpers/Attribute.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\RestFilters\Helpers;

class Attribute 
{
    public static function sobstitute($attribute)
    {
        $hashMap = [
            'gt' => '>',
            'gte' => '>=',
            'lt' => '<',
            'lte' => '<=',
            'like' => 'like',
            'ilike' => 'ilike'
        ];

        return array_key_exists($attribute, $hashMap) ?
            $hashMap[$attribute] :
            false;
    }
}
```

To make it work, you can now add the `$fieldMapping` property to your model

```php
// App/Models/TrafficViolation.php

class TrafficViolation extends Model
{
    public array $fieldMapping = [
        'location' => 'location_relationship_id'
    ];
}
```

And don't forget to register your new ServiceProvider in app.php

```php
// config/app.php

$providers = [
    ...
    \App\Providers\RestServiceProvider::class,
]
```

This should allow you to now define mappings on each of your models